# Is it possible to send a message to a user's friend using the Bots for Messenger API?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I am looking at using the new Facebook Messenger API to send a message to a user's friend.

For example:

Alice's messenger session:

> Alice: Send this result to Bob
>
> Bot: Did you mean Bob Smith?
>
> Alice: Yes
>
> Bot: OK, sent.

On Bob's messenger:

> Bot: Alice wanted to let you know that x

Obviously Facebook has to have some spam control in place.

Is this scenario possible *without* Bob having to connect with the Messenger bot first?

Comment: I hope not … sounds like ti would generate a lot of spam.

Comment: Very much doubt it. The user ID's you use to send a message to a user, or get their name/profile picture, are contextual to your facebook page. For example, if one user chat to both Page A and Page B - the user ID those pages receive for that user are both different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way how to send post to an "unknown" user is try "customer matching" (one time $99 fee).

From [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#phone_number):

> When messages are sent to phone numbers, we will only send the message
>   if we have a certain level of confidence of expected delivery. If you
>   find that during testing you cannot message your own phone number,
>   re-verify it under Facebook user settings and wait 24 hours. At that
>   point, you should be able to successfully send a message to your own
>   phone.

Answer (score 1):

recently they introduce the Share Button. This button can be included on a generic template. The problem is that the message will be sent by the user who clicks on Share and not by the bot.

Here the reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/share-button